# FFMPEG NReco.ConcatMedia merging files from different sources

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, nreco

need help with follow issue.
I downloaded 3 videos from youtube, and cut that with NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter.ConvertMedia to small pieces with follow code:

```
        ffMpegConverter.ConvertMedia (SourceFile, Format.mp4, tempVideo, Format.mp4,
        new ConvertSettings () {
            Seek = StartTime,
            MaxDuration = (EndTime - StartTime),
            VideoCodec = "libx264",
            AudioCodec = "mp3",
            CustomOutputArgs = string.Format ("-vf \"pad=640:360:x=(640-iw)/2:y=(360-ih)/2:color=black\" -af \"volume = {0}dB\"", volumeMultiplier),
            VideoFrameRate = 25,
            AudioSampleRate = 44100,
            VideoFrameSize = "640x360"
        });
```

And added watermark (with just inline ffmpeg command):

```
-i {0} -i {1} -filter_complex \"[1:v]scale={3}:{4},format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa={5}[wat];[0:v][wat]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-{6}:main_h-overlay_h-{7} [out]\" -map \"[out]\" -map 0:a -y {2}
```

And when i concating video pieces from sources #1 and #2 it's ok, but not with #3. I belive it some kind of compatibility issue between (#1, #2) and (#3) formats, but that should be fixed at ConvertMedia stage, isn't? May be I missed some of OutPut parameters?

Sample MediaInfo for file from source #3 https://jpst.it/Zoof

And one for file from source #2 https://jpst.it/ZooC

Why that files can't be joined, where to search a reason?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found a reason why NReco didnt merged that files, but I wrote own wrapper

```
     static void Main (string[] args) {
        concatMedia (new string[] {
        args[0], args[1]
        }, args[2]);
     }

    private static string makeTempFile (string fileName) {
        FFMpegConverter c = new FFMpegConverter ();
        FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo (fileName);
        string tempFile = Path.Combine (fileInfo.DirectoryName, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension (fileName) + ".ts");
        c.Invoke (string.Format ("-i {0} -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -y {1}", fileName, tempFile));
        return tempFile;
    }

    private static void concatMedia (string[] files, string output) {
        FFMpegConverter c = new FFMpegConverter ();
        List<string> tempFiles = new List<string> ();
        foreach (var item in files) {
            tempFiles.Add (makeTempFile (item));
        }
        c.Invoke (string.Format ("-i \"concat:{0}\" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -y {1}", string.Join ("|", tempFiles), output));
        foreach (var item in tempFiles) {
            System.IO.File.Delete (item);
        }
    }
```